# SavedGameRequestStatus.InternalError google play services

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I have a problem with Google Play Save Games.
Authorization with Google Play Services is working fine. And I'm using EnableSavedGames(), DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime.
But when I'm trying to access saved sessions, I get InternalError message.

Screenshot with API Goodle Drive calls included:
[GoogleDriveApiMethods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebVd.png)
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but for me, the problem was in this bit of obscure documentation: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#incremental-authorization

> This will allow silent sign-in to succeed, because silent sign-in will always fail if you ask for more than GAMES_LITE and, if you use Saved Games, DRIVE.APP_DATA.

Specifically I needed to request permissions for Drive:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestPermission("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata", permissionResult => {

        if (permissionResult == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(GOOGLE_PLAY_FILENAME, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, OnSavedGameOpened);
        }
    });
```